# how to customize chrome theme per window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-theme

I usually have three chrome windows open. To easily distinguish my work chrome from the personal chrome window, I would like to set a theme to one window, and another theme to other windows.

I figure out how to change the theme globally, wondering whether its possible to it per window.

Comment: You may want to refer on this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes)

Comment: @LexJulienne, Little info there

Comment: Yeah I would like to change the Chrome theme programmatically. The linked documentation talks about setting the theme with manifest.json, but I need to change the theme dynamically.

Comment: and what about sharing bookmarks between profiles ( I have a shared set and a individual set of bookmarks....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use different profiles. You can do this in chrome by clicking the Proflile icon in the top-right of any window. It'll ask you to log in with your Google account but you're able to make a local account with any name.

I use one for personal (personal google account), one for work (work google account), and a third with no google account for risky or other website browsing (which has more aggressive blocking rules)

Comment: You can launch a specific profile with the command line flag `--profile-directory=Default`

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile

Answer (score 4):

I do have in mind 2 options, since I really want to easily identify them.

[image]
[image]

You can add name to your window, not so noticeable since only shows on hover on mac.

---

[image]

You can also group all the tabs in that window, to give it a bit of a different color

[image]

which you can see here. blue and red. Bit noticeable.

for windows users, can you try this options, it might be better there.

Answer (score -3):

I did some research into this issue, and it seems the only way to do this is to open different browsers e.g - firefox for presonal stuff, chrome for work etc...
will be happy to see a better solotion though...